# Adjusting line height in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, cout

I am attempting to put the final touches on a maze program I have been writing. I have used Unicode to delimit the walls and paths however because of the (horizontal) line spacing I can't quite get it to look compact enough. I have attached two screenshots. I'm just escaping the newline "\n" in order to print each row. Can the distance between lines be adjusted or am I stuck with this "gappy" representation?

My output:

[image: my output - with gaps between rows]

What I am trying to closely represent:

[image: desired output - no gaps between rows]

Comment: You want us to help you and you don't even show us your code (?!).

Comment: Your terminal and its font selection are what affect the line height. You most likely can't control it from within your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you aren't printing double newlines, this is outside the scope of standard C++, it does not provide facilities for controlling terminal in a standard way.

Solutions:

- You could provide a launcher script, which opens a new terminal window with specific font and runs your app in it.
- You could use some platform specific method to change background color (ANSI codes work in unixy terminals, or use Win32 API for Windows terminal, ncurses library on Unix-like environments) and print just spaces in different colors.
- Use a GUI library/framework to get complete control on what is drawn (I'd use Qt for C++ GUI app).

Answer (score -1):

TBH if you want pixel-accurate rendering use a proper rendering API, such as OpenGL.

From a text rendering point of view you don't say what you are rendering to. Assuming something like a terminal console or shell window then the layout beyond characters and newlines is nothing to do with your program; the visual representation is entirely determined by the shell you are rendering to.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment. (Not yet downvoted).

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, check that you are genuinely printing a line per maze scan line, and not interleaving with spurious newlines. Assuming that is ruled out, the problem is that the unicode glyph is not a full block. So you must somehow set the font or choose another glyph which is a full block.

Usually console windows are 80 characters wide by 22 or 24 characters high, and characters are 8 pixels wide by 19 pixels high. So it's very far from a square grid, and you might want to bias the maze to reflect that and provide a better visual appearance (eg make 2 pixel-wide vertical corridors much more common than 2-pievel wide horizontal corridors).

Do check the binary image library fonts, you might find them useful.

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/binaryimagelibrary